# Can't GET css files from express.js public folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This is the server side of my react app, and I'm seriously gobsmacked because I think I've done everything right... I've looked at a lot of posts here and also the express docs themselves, and still I'm getting a 404 when trying to get a single css file from my public folder:

My directory structure:

```
/server
  app.js 
  /views
    main.js
  /public
    /css
      styles.css
```

The generated html from main.js which is sent with
response.set("Content-Type", "text/html").send(htmlDoc);

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

In app.js

```
app.use(router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This always results in:

```
"GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

What else can I check?

Comment: try putting ```app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));``` before ```app.use(router);```

Comment: @NilupulSandeepa I've tried that before but it also results in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

since you already set "public" folder as publicly available via

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

any time express needs to send a file, it will look into "public" folder. in your case it will look for styles.css file inside public folder